# Forma correcta de abrir HTML en Modal BootStrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

Tengo lo siguiente, tengo 4 archivos html con informacón diferente que necesito mostrar según se necesario, ya tengo esto heco y funciona pero no se si es la forma correcto o se puede mejorar, agradezco su ayuda

Index.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Ventana Modal con Bootstrap</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="carga_ajax('12','myModal','ajax_1.html');">Modal 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="carga_ajax('12','myModal','ajax_2.html');">Modal 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Funcion

```
function carga_ajax(id,div,url){
$.post
(url, {id:id}, function(resp){
        $("#"+div+"").html(resp);
   }
 );
}
```

Y este es el archivo modal_info01.html que contendrá la información

```
<!-- Modal -->

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Este es Modal 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como les comentaba... esto si me funciona la consulta es.... es la mejor forma de hacerlo o se puede mejorar

La única pregunta que les tendria es porque debe de poner este linea en el index

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    </div>
```

Comment: Te referis a tabindex="-1" ?

Comment: Es que me di cuenta que si pongo esa linea en el archivo del modal no hace nada.. lo volvi a poner enel index y ahora si funcionó pero no se porque .... no se si es lo correcto o no, Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Sería interesante conocer qué versión de bootstrap estás utilizando. Asumiré que usas la última versión.

La forma adecuada, a mi entender, habiendo leído la documentación oficial (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/) es:

1. Configurar en el HTML la estructura del modal. Bootstrap espera que tu modal tenga cierta estructura.

Al final de tu pregunta mencionas que tienes una duda con el cierta etiqueta en tu index:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
</div>
```

Esta etiqueta es el modal. Sin esa etiqueta no hay modal, por eso si no la pones no se carga nada. Esto es así dado que en los enlaces que usas para cargar el modal apuntas al mismo:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="carga_ajax('12','myModal','ajax_1.html');">Modal 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="carga_ajax('12','myModal','ajax_2.html');">Modal 2</a>
```

Como ves, el atributo data-target toma el valor "#myModal", lo cual quiere decir que, una vez que la librería de bootstrap realice su tarea de configuración, esos enlaces apuntarán al elemento con id igual a "myModal". El elemento con id igual a "myModal" es:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
</div>
```

Veo que la estructura del modal es cargada mediante AJAX. Esto, en mi opinión, es un error. La estructura (tu modal dialog, header y body) debe ser incluida directamente (en el HTML), cargarlo por AJAX podría causar un comportamiento inesperado cuando cambies de versión y, por lo que sea, cambie el orden en el que se desencadenen los eventos "click" de los enlaces.

No voy a entrar en si el cuerpo del modal (los datos que tú quieres cambiar) deben ser cargados por AJAX o no. Depende del escenario en concreto.

En resumen, que tu modal debería de conservar la estructura y que, si decides cargar datos por AJAX, cargues el título de la cabecera y el cuerpo del modal ("Este es Modal 2" y el contenido de la etiqueta con clase "modal-body").

Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Roberto, gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad es que estoy usando la versión 3.3.7 de bootstrap.

La verdad es que no sabia que estaba usando ajax para cargar el modal (yo encontré el código en un sitio pero no vi que era ajax), como se podría cargar el modal sin usan Ajax pero que siempre cargue los archivos ?

Gracias por tu ayuda o la de cualquiera que desee aportar su opinión

Gracias

Comment: Hola Joe, para cargar el archivo tienes que solicitarlo. La forma más popular de hacerlo es mediante Ajax. El usar Ajax en sí no es malo, pero úsalo para cargar los datos que realmente te sean relevantes, como la cabecera y el cuerpo. La estructura del modal probablemente vaya a ser la misma, por lo que es mejor dejarla en el Html. Te he preparado un ejemplo en JsFiddle para que puedas ver el proceso. El modal está definido en el HTML, pero los datos son cargados mediante Ajax: http://jsfiddle.net/9rfmzwt4/81/

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si no quieres cargar el archivo no necesitarías usar Ajax, como puedes ver en: http://jsfiddle.net/34vprf60/